# Calll WebAPI in Webforms application from C#, authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I have a WebForms application which expose some WebAPI methods. The application uses standard Forms Authentication. I'm able to call methods from browser when I properly authenticated.

Now I want to call the API from c# application using HttpClient, but always receiving error 403 "Forbidden".

I can see that cookies container contains SessionId cookie.

The code:

```
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        // authenticate
        {
            var webRequestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
            webRequestHandler.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            webRequestHandler.UseCookies = true;

            var client = new HttpClient(webRequestHandler);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost/<WEBFORMSAPP>/");

            string unid = "<USERNAME$FIELD$NAME>";
            string pwdid = "<PASSWORD$FIELD$NAME>";
            HttpContent loginData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
                new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(unid, "<USERNAME>"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(pwdid, "<PASSWORD>"),
                }
                );

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

            var postResult = client.PostAsync("<LOGINPAGE.aspx>", loginData);
            postResult.Wait();
            postResult.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }

        // call web api
        {
            var webRequestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
            webRequestHandler.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            webRequestHandler.UseCookies = true;

            var client = new HttpClient(webRequestHandler);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost/<WEBFORMSAPP>/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            var r = client.GetAsync("api/<SOME_METHOD>");
            r.Wait();

            r.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Fails with 403 error
        }
```

Comment: You are probably receiving a 403 as well as an instruction to redirect somewhere. Unless you host a web browser within the application and grab the cookies, I think you have to start looking at alternative to form authentication for this scenario.

Comment: Well this is partialy true.
The web forms app replaces original 302 code with 403 to avoid redirection to the login page when the user is not authenticated.
I can't avoid forms authentication. I believe there should be the way to programmatically create authentication cookies and logon into the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build the proper web request we need to provide server with the correct __VIEWSTATE value and the name of the button which cause the postback (in addition to the login/password pair).

To do this first we need to make a GET request to the login page and extract then __VIEWSTATE value.

I have used code from this blog post:
http://odetocode.com/articles/162.aspx

The code to create authorization cookies:

```
    public CookieContainer CreateAuthorizationCookies(string login, string password)
    {
        var result = new CookieContainer();

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

        var webRequestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
        webRequestHandler.CookieContainer = result;
        webRequestHandler.UseCookies = true;

        var client = new HttpClient(webRequestHandler);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://*********/");

        // get viewstate
        string viewstate;
        {
            var r = client.GetStringAsync("***/LoginPage.aspx");
            r.Wait();
            // see http://odetocode.com/articles/162.aspx
            viewstate = ExtractViewState(r.Result);
        }

        HttpContent loginData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
            new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("__VIEWSTATE", viewstate),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("***$UserName", login),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("***$Password", password),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("***$LoginButton", "Log In"), // "value" of the HTML input element
            }
            );

        var postResult = client.PostAsync("****/LoginPage.aspx", loginData);
        postResult.Wait();
        postResult.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return result;
    }
```

After that we can use created CookieContainer in the further requests.